# Oracle correlated subquery, filter results

Tags: database, oracle, subquery, correlated

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:** 
First of all, thanks to @Nick for finding the solution that you can see below.
Second, I attach the code needed to execute the query as correlated.

```
SELECT L.num_pedido, PR.codigo, PR.nombre, PR.precio AS "Producto más caro"
FROM lineas L, productos PR
WHERE L.producto=PR.codigo
    AND (PR.precio) = (
                    SELECT MAX(PR2.precio)
                    FROM lineas L2, productos PR2
                    WHERE L2.producto=PR2.codigo
                        AND L2.num_pedido=L.num_pedido
                    )
ORDER BY L.num_pedido;
```

I have a problem with an apparently simple exercise.
I show you first the tables involved:

[image]

The exercise asks: "Data of the most expensive product of each order (with a correlated query)"

Apparently, after searching this website I quickly found the solution, the problem is that I think I still do not execute the solution correctly. This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.num_pedido, PR.codigo, PR.nombre, PR.precio AS "Max. precio unidad"
FROM lineas L, productos PR
WHERE L.producto=PR.codigo
    AND (precio) = (
                    SELECT MAX(precio)
                    FROM productos PR2
                    WHERE PR.codigo=PR2.codigo
                    )
ORDER BY L.num_pedido
```

But still I can not get it to filter by "num_pedido" (order number).The resulting table should look like this, omitting the rows crossed out in red:

[image]

[image]

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS (
CODIGO  NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
PRECIO   NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE  LINEAS    (   
NUM NUMBER(2,0), 
NUM_PEDIDO NUMBER(5,0), 
PRODUCTO NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL , 
CANTIDAD NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL , 
IMPORTE NUMBER(6,2), 
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (NUM, NUM_PEDIDO) , 
 CONSTRAINT PEDIDO_FK FOREIGN KEY (NUM_PEDIDO)
  REFERENCES  PEDIDOS (NUM) , 
 CONSTRAINT PRODUCTO_FK FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTO)
  REFERENCES  PRODUCTOS (CODIGO) 
   );
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (10001, 'PANTALÓN', 50);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (10002, 'PANTALÓN PITILLO', 60);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (10003, 'PANTALÓN CAMPANA', 55);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (20001, 'CAMISA M/L', 65);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (20002, 'CAMISA M/C', 45);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (30001, 'VESTIDO C', 80);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (30002, 'VESTIDO L', 90);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (40001, 'FALDA LARGA', 50);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (40002, 'FALDA CORTA', 45);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (40003, 'FALDA MINI', 40);

INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,1, 10001, 2, 100);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (2,1, 30001, 1, 80);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (3,1, 20001, 2, 130);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,2, 20001, 1, 65);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (2,2, 40003, 3, 120);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,3, 40002, 2, 180);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,4, 10001, 2, 100);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,5, 20002, 2, 90);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (2,5, 40002, 1, 45);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,6, 40002, 1, 45);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,7, 40002, 1, 45);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,8, 40002, 1, 45);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,9, 40003, 1, 40);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (2,9, 20002, 1, 45);
INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,10,20002, 2, 90);
```

I know it's probably a very simple error, but I can not find the solution.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: which is the orders table? im guessing productos is the products table ? :)

Comment: Hi, orders table is BD04.Pedidos and BD04.Productos is the products table. 
I think it is not necessary to go to the table "orders", because from the "lines" table appears the item "order number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works:

```
SELECT A.NUM_PEDIDO, A.CODIGO, A.NOMBRE, A.PRECIO FROM (
  SELECT L.NUM_PEDIDO, PR.CODIGO, PR.NOMBRE, PR.PRECIO,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY L.NUM_PEDIDO ORDER BY PR.PRECIO DESC) RANKORDER
  FROM LINEAS L INNER JOIN PRODUCTOS PR ON L.PRODUCTO =PR.CODIGO
)A WHERE RANKORDER = 1
```

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression" If I write only: "ORDER BY L.num_pedido",  the following appears: 1 10001 PANTALÓN 50

Comment: I really appreciate your help.
Now it shows the maximum only of the first order, that is:

1 30001 DRESS C 80

Comment: Ok, so the result has only one row?

Comment: I tried to imitate these examples [link](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/correlated-subquery.php), since at first it seemed easy, but I can not find the solution.

Comment: Sorry i dont speak spanish. try the edited code now

Comment: No, I must obtain the maximum value of each order. Now I'm going to edit the second image, with the results that I should provide.

Comment: Thanks again, but with your new code, it shows the same as in the second image of my post. That is, do not omit products that are not the maximum value in each order. I can not get what I show in the third image. Sorry, if I do not explain myself correctly.

Comment: Ok ill need to try and recreate your table and test out a query

Comment: I just edited the post with the tables and their data.

Comment: @Snake_9x your requirement needs more than a correlated query to filter within rows. The edited code above should work :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! Now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: That is not using a correlated query.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak 
You're right. I just found the solution through correlated query. Now I edit the post. Anyway, the previous user's method is perfectly valid.